# How to add text in row header using code behind for DataGrid in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

I have a DataGrid which is populated with an array.
How do I add text in row header using code behind?
So far I've added data like this.

```
public static DataView GetBindable2DArray<T>(T[,] array)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(1); i++)
        {
            dataTable.Columns.Add(i.ToString(), typeof(Ref<T>));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }
        DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                int a = i;
                int b = j;
                Ref<T> refT = new Ref<T>(() => array[a, b], z => { array[a, b] = z; });
                dataView[i][j] = refT;
            }
        }
        return dataView;
    }
```

The XAML

```
<DataGrid x:Name="tableDataGrid" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="6" Grid.Column="0" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="True"
              ColumnWidth="*"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
              RowHeaderWidth="100" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="Cell"
               HeadersVisibility="All" CanUserAddRows="False">
      
    </DataGrid>
```

ItemSource

```
            tableDataGrid.ItemsSource = GetBindable2DArray<double>(dataArray);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for was answerd with [Loading row event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417505/numbering-row-header-in-datagrid-using-c-sharp) and [enter link description here](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/302079/numbering-row-header-in-datagrid-using-c)

```
private void tableDataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Row.Header = e.Row.GetIndex();
    }
```